# Averaging the slope of multiple lines

Tags: average, slope

I have 25 different trend lines. I'm interested in rate of change, which will be given by the slope of these lines.

While searching on the internet, i came across this interesting post, [What good can come from averaging a slope](https://web.archive.org/web/20180209020254/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/77932.html).

They are talking about average of slope of 2 lines.
I want a trend line that is showing the general trend followed by these 25 lines. Can I imply take the arithmetic mean of these slopes? If not, then what is the possible solution?

Comment: What are these trendlines for? Do you have the raw data? What type of data are these? These can affect the answer quite drastically. It will be good if you provide further context.

Comment: This is human muscle activity, with the passage of time, the activity increases and these trend lines are demonstrating the rate of change in muscle activity.

Comment: I see. Then yes, taking arithmetic mean of the slopes is the most appropriate here.